# APCIterator Fatal error - no search RegEx

Tags: php, apc

This should be very straight forward? The second argument in the APCIterator constructor is a string, or array of strings, containing RegEx search patterns. The manual [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/apciterator.construct.php) says to optionally pass null to skip the search. It is in fact an optional argument with a null default value.

```
$iter = new APCIterator('user');

$cache = array();

while($iter->valid()) {
  $cache[$iter->key()] = $iter->current();
  $iter->next();
}
```

this results in the following errors:

> Warning:  APCIterator::__construct(): Delimiter must not be
> alphanumeric or backslash in /usr/share/nginx/html/beta/test.php on
> line 16
>
> Fatal error:  APCIterator::__construct(): Could not compile regular
> expression: user in /usr/share/nginx/html/beta/test.php on line 16

*tagged as APC, but this is technically APCU*

Answer (score 0):

the APCIterator in APCU has "user" hardcoded into it. The arguments are all shifted to the left once.

```
$iter = new APCIterator();
```

works properly.